# Getting exception while adding datepicker in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jqgrid

I am getting below exception while adding datepicker :

```
Uncaught TypeError: a.getAttribute is not a function
    at M._attachDatepicker (jquery-ui-core.min.js:489)
    at Object.<anonymous> (jquery-ui-core.min.js:553)
    at Function.each (jquery-1.6.2.js:16)
    at init.each (jquery-1.6.2.js:16)
    at init.d.fn.datepicker (jquery-ui-core.min.js:553)
    at Object.dataInit (common.js:1042)
    at h (jquery.jqGrid.min.js:4229)
    at Object.createEl (jquery.jqGrid.min.js:4376)
    at Object.<anonymous> (jquery.jqGrid.min.js:4859)
    at Function.each (jquery-1.6.2.js:16)
_attachDatepicker @ jquery-ui-core.min.js:489
```

Col Model :

```
{
            name:'billDate',
            index:'billDate',
            formatter: 'date',
            sortable:false,
            align:'center',
            editable:true,
            edittype:"text",
            hidden:'true',
            editoptions: {
                size: 20,
                maxlengh: 10,
                dataInit: function (element) {
                    $(this).datepicker({
                        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                        constrainInput: false,
                        showOn: 'button',
                        buttonText: '...'
                    });
                }
            },
            editrules: {
                date: true,
                minValue: 0
            },
            formatoptions: {
                newformat: "Y-m-d"
            }
        }
```

I am using JQGrid 4.0.0

Comment: You wrote "I am using JQuery 4.0.0". You mean probably jqGrid 4.0.0. Which version of jQuery UI you use? The stack of the error shows that you try to use jQuery 1.6.2, which can't be used with the retro version jqGrid 4.0.0. It's too new for jqGrid 4.0.0. **If you want (have to) continue to use jqGrid 4.0.0 then you have to use jQuery in version prior 1.6.** You have to use only retro versions of jQuery UI too.

Comment: Sorry JQGRID 4.0.0 I ham using

Comment: **Which version of jQuery UI you use?** `datepicker` is the widget of jQuery UI. In any way you have to downgrade jQuery to 1.4.4 or 1.5.2. Do you tried to downgrade to jQuery? Which error you get now?

Comment: I am using JQuery 1.6.0

Comment: I repeat that you **can't** use jQuery 1.6, because it contains many changes in working with attributes and properties. The retro version jqGrid 4.0.0 have to be used with retro versions of jQuery and jQuery UI. It's the same like you have to use diesel, if your car has diesel motor. You can't fill the auto with petrol or to drive with electricity.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to continue to use retro version of jqGrid 4.0.0 then you **have to** use retro versions of jQuery and jQuery UI. The stack of the error message shows that you tried to use jQuery 1.6.2 with jqGrid 4.0.0. It's impossible. jQuery methods of working with attributes and properties was changed in jQuery 1.6. The old jqGrid 4.0.0 uses `jQuery.attr` instead of `jQuery.prop`.

Short explained: one can compare jqGrid 4.0.0 with a steam motor. You can't use steam motor with diesel, petrol, gas or electricity.

You have to downgrade jQuery, which you use to version 1.4.4 or 1.5.2 to be able to use jqGrid 4.0.0.

Alternatively you can upgrade jqGrid 4.0.0 to free jqGrid 4.14.0 and to use almost any version of jQuery starting with 1.7.2. Recommended versions of jQuery would be 3.2.1, 2.2.4 or 1.12.4. You will be able to use free jqGrid 4.14.0 with any jQuery UI starting with 1.8 (for example 1.8.24) till the latest 1.12.1 or to use Bootstrap 3.x or 4.0.0-alpha6 alternatively.